# Group POlicy and Default Printer by Computer

Tags: group-policy, shared-printers

We have multiple sites with specific printers to be assigned to each location. All the printers reside on the same print server.

We have group policies (Windows 2008) in place to deploy specific printers to each site but running into issues setting a default printer based on its location at the site. Meaning that at Site A we are deploying printers X, Y, and Z, and in area B of Site A make printer X the default, printer Y the default in area C of Site A, etc. no matter who logs into the computer.

I an see how to set a default printer using the User Configuration, but we want to do a default printer off the Computer Configuration, or something that isn't tied to a specific user.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at using a loopback policy in merge mode perhaps?  This will apply **user** settings from the Computer OU.

Comment: NoI haven't... First I heard of it. Looking into it now. Thanks